# .Net Application logging

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello all I have a scenario where i have one winform app as server and infinite number of winform apps as clients

basically each client connects to server and sends a string to server , server than do some calculations and return string back to client, but server have to connect to another server for calculation of that string and in response from that second server our main server stores the response in a string variable and after some specific time intervals it shows that string variable in a textbox but this string gets bigger and bigger after each calculation and hence my server some times starts consuming 1gb memory in task manager and 40% of my cpu usage , and when i removed the string variable my server was running on 45mb of memory and 0-4% of cpu usage i am using string variable like this

```
string Serverlog += datafetched + "cl"
```

i have also tried a string builder object but result is same so can any one help me to sort out things ( how can i save logs without consuming to much memory ) and one thing more logs will not be maitained in any file they are only for showing them into textbox

Comment: Why not use a logging framework such as log4net?

Comment: Your Serverlog string is going get infinitely large over time.  You need to think about the data that you're logging and presenting.  Is it really necessary to have all the data saved in memory?  As @Kippie said you could use a logging framework like log4net or Microsoft's [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx)

Comment: i dont want logging for myself or any other admin so saving in file is not what i need , logging over server is just for a person who is moderating server and it is really important to store all logs as we need it for something important , and one reason i am avoiding file system is that this is a multithreaded application and currently this app have so much IO involved so things will get worse if i use file system as ultimately i have to show logs in textbox and when i was using textbox.Append method my ui was becoming hell slow after some K of data i am currently updating 2-3 grids also

Comment: Client sends approx 400-500 strings a second to Server and in mean time Server calculates the string store the results in variable and send data back to client so think if server is running for a day or two and 1000 clients are connected what will be the outcome

Comment: @AdilsAdils And you want 4,320,000,000 lines of data available on a UI log at the same time? Even if it was logging only to files you'd need a new hard drive every week.

Comment: currently i will be working with 100 clients this is just a test phase in production it may reach to that limit or may be more than that i dont have any other choice as i have to log this on UI

Comment: @AdilsAdils Then you need to **drastically** reduce the amount of data you're logging, or find a **much** more compact way of displaying it. Even if it were technically possible, how do you expect your user to scroll up and down a textbox with 4 billion lines in it?

Comment: ok thnx rotem means i have to destroy some logs for better performance as there is no way out i will think about it what logs i can destroy and what to keep

Comment: @AdilsAdils You can destroy data that is X minutes/hours old. But also consider that if your log is adding hundreds of lines per second, and deleting the same amount of lines per second, how will a user be able to read any of it? It will all look like a big blur, and will most likely bring your UI thread to a screeching halt. You should consider writing all data to a file, and displaying only very important data in the UI as well, e.g. warning/error messages.

Comment: Also be aware, if you're saving the log in memory you'll lose the data if the application stops for whatever reason.  You really need to look at some form of persistence, be it file, database or whatever if the data is as you say "really important to store all logs as we need it for something important".

Comment: yeah data is important but i also have mentioned that this app is already utilizing to much IO so will it be safe to use file system and append data to file with such speed i can not compromise on speed of execution so i can not use any db for that

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to store your logging somewhere, database / file / winlogging / other

What kind of app are you running on the clients? Be aware that u use the **AppendText** function of the textbox. So dont use:

```
Textbox.Text += "additional info"
```

but use

```
Textbox.AppendText(teTonenTekst + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

While logging to a file is best, you mentioned you do not want that.

For UI based logging, I usually avoid a `TextBox`, and instead use a `ListView` or `DataGridView` with hidden gridlines. That way it is easy to truncate the amount of values to a limit, keeping only recent data in the control.

It is also easier to color code different types of logging data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the text in to the file or MSMQ or Telnet and clear the variable. While displaying the contents read from one of the above mentioned source.

Answer (score 0):

You should be used `text file` for logging application actions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store the logs in a file instead of keeping everythingin a variable. I personaly always do that by using a logging function which creates an individual log file for each user each day. Like that you have a better control over your logs and dont have to worry about your preformance problem. Have a look at this example:

```
    internal static void WriteLog(string str, string clientNumber)
    {

        StreamWriter logWriter = null;

        string todayDateString = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        string fullLogFileName = todayDateString + "_" + clientNumber + "_log.txt";
        string LogPath = @"\\server\folder\Logs\";

        string fullLogFilePathWithName = LogPath + fullLogFileName;


        if (!File.Exists(fullLogFilePathWithName))
        {
            logWriter = new StreamWriter(fullLogFilePathWithName, true);

            logWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d.MM.yyyy h:mm") + " - " + str);
            logWriter.Flush();
        }
        else
        {
            logWriter = File.AppendText(fullLogFilePathWithName);

            logWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d.MM.yyyy h:mm") + " - " + str);
            logWriter.Flush();
        }

        logWriter.Dispose();
        logWriter.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In multithread application this is definitely a must have.

Answer (score 0):

.net already has built in support for tracing / logging:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68.aspx
However, we use log4net, and I'm quite happy with it:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/
From your question it is not quite clear if the log is displayed by the server or the client. However, log4net has support for logging over the net, e.g. an [UPD Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.UdpAppender.html).